# AndroidStudio Robotium web:java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null

Tags: android, android-studio, robotium

When I running robotium in Android Studio,there is something wrong with it, Should I do some configure to run js?

solo.sleep(5*1000);
Assert.assertTrue("OpenWebUrlError", solo.waitForWebElement(By.textContent("找不到网页")));

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:64)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:122)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:59)
at com.robotium.solo.WebUtils.getJavaScriptAsString(WebUtils.java:354)
at com.robotium.solo.WebUtils.prepareForStartOfJavascriptExecution(WebUtils.java:162)
at com.robotium.solo.WebUtils.executeJavaScriptFunction(WebUtils.java:276)
at com.robotium.solo.WebUtils.executeJavaScript(WebUtils.java:238)
at com.robotium.solo.WebUtils.getWebElements(WebUtils.java:111)
at com.robotium.solo.Searcher.searchForWebElement(Searcher.java:238)
at com.robotium.solo.Waiter.waitForWebElement(Waiter.java:498)
at com.robotium.solo.Solo.waitForWebElement(Solo.java:672)
```

Comment: post your code also

Comment: Assert.assertTrue("OpenWebUrlError", solo.waitForWebElement(By.textContent("找不到网页")));